# TypeError on form submission with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, phantomjs

Since my mobile phone provider no longer provides an SMS gateway email address, I'm writing a little application using PhantomJS to log into their website and send an SMS message using their webtext forms.

The problem is that the application works very infrequently. I've managed to send a few SMS messages but most of the time it fails to execute. Here's the program and Javascript code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace textSender {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var phantomJS = new PhantomJS();

        phantomJS.OutputReceived += (sender, e) => {
            Console.WriteLine("PhantomJS output: {0}", e.Data);
        };
        phantomJS.ErrorReceived += (sender, e) => {
            Console.WriteLine("PhantomJS error: {0}", e.Data);
        };

        // execute login.js
        Console.WriteLine("Loading data from <carrier website>");
        try {
            phantomJS.Run(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "login.js"), new[] { "<carrier webtext URL>" });

        } finally {
            phantomJS.Abort();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Execution finished. Press enter to close.");
        Console.In.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Fairly basic, based off of one of the PhantomJS examples.

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();

var fillLoginInfo = function () {
    var loginForm = document.getElementById("UserLoginForm");
    loginForm.elements["UserTelephoneNo"].value = '<phone number>';
    loginForm.elements["UserPin"].value = '<password>';
    loginForm.submit();
}

var fillMessageInfo = function () {

    var messForm = document.getElementById("MessageSendForm");
    messForm.elements["MessageMessage"].value = 'This message was sent automatically';
    messForm.elements["MessageRecipientsIndividual0"].value = '<phoneNumber>';
    messForm.submit();
    console.log("Message sent");
}

page.onLoadFinished = function () {

    if (page.title == "<Homepage Title>") {
        console.log("Login page");
        page.evaluate(fillLoginInfo);
        return;
    }
    else if (page.title == "Webtext Page Title") {
        console.log("Message page");
        page.evaluate(fillMessageInfo);
        return;
    }
    else
        page.render('./screens/some.png');

    console.log("completed");
    phantom.exit();
}

page.open(system.args[1]);
```

Just to briefly explain what should be happening in login.js;

1. The page opens the url passed in from Program.cs
2. OnLoadFinished triggers when the page opens, executing fillLoginInfo
3. fillLoginInfo submits the form, navigating to the webtext page
4. onloadFinished triggers again when the webtext page has loaded
5. fillMessageInfo is executed, the SMS is sent

Based on the few console.log commands dotted around, the expected output would be:

```
Loading data from <carrier website>...
PhantomJS output: Login Page
PhantomJS output: Message Page
PhantomJS output: Message Sent
PhantomJS output: completed
Execution finished. Press enter to close.
```

Instead, I'm seeing this:

```
Loading data from <carrier website>...
PhantomJS output: Login Page
PhantomJS output: Message Page
PhantomJS output: Message Page
PhantomJS output: Message Page
PhantomJS output: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'messForm.elements')
PhantomJS output: Message Page
PhantomJS output: Message Page
```

and so on.

The TypeError is making me think that the javascript is trying to execute before the DOM is fully loaded but in that case, why would page.onLoadFinished be triggered? Similarly, if it's executing before the DOM is fully loaded, why is it loading up the message page repeatedly? A successful form submission reloads the page so the fact that it's looping like that makes me think it's successfully submitting, though clearly it isn't.

The most I've been able to figure out is that the fillMessageInfo function stops executing after assigning a value to messForm, which makes sense with the error referring to its elements in the next line.

It may be something stupidly simple but I've been looking at this for too long and just need a fresh set of eyes to tell me why I'm wrong.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks for the tip. After registering to those events it appears that this question may be a duplicate of [Unable to load page resources with PhantomJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963609/unable-to-load-page-resources-with-phantomjs) which unfortunately has no answer. One or more resources are failing to load so it's cancelling the operation. For reference [here](https://www.three.ie/wp-content/themes/three.ie/js/s_code.js?_1473840232706) is one of the resources failing to load.


P.S. forgot to mention I'm using version 2.0.0

Comment: You can try to use PhantomJS 1.9.8 to see if you see more errors (v2.x has a bug with showing some errors). Have you tried to run PhantomJS with `--web-security=false`?